# How to use bottomsheet as an overlay over any app

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, bottom-sheet

I am working on an app that is supposed to show definitions of a word when a user highlights a word in any app. I am using a service to make the network call and all is fine up until the point when I want to implement bottomsheets. If my root layout is a LinearLayout, I get to inflate the view easily in my service class. If I make the root layout a CoordinatorLayout, I get an error about having to implement theme.appcompat. Because I couldn't proceed with this as I can't use bottomsheet without a coordinatorlayout, I used Flipboard's bottomsheet and another library but still can't get it to work.

How do I please get a bottomsheet to be a bottom overlay over any app. Please note that I would be setting the values of the bottomsheet from a service class.

Thanks.

Comment: You just need to wrap the `Service` `Context` in a `ContextThemeWrapper` with an `AppCompat` theme, and pass that to your `LayoutInflater`. The linked duplicate shows how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikeM.